# Player rotating in circles instead of moving in straight lines

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm building a Third Peron Perspective movement of a Player Object in Unity. The Camera is supposed to be following the player from behind and rotate when the player rotates so that it always faces the player's back. I'm WASD keys for the player's movement. The player initially moved in straight lines upon pressing those keys. After implementing the camera rotation, when I press A or D key, the player is moving in circles instead of straight lines. I believe it is a problem with my camera rotation but I have no Idea how to fix it.

My Player's Locomotion code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;


public class PlayerLocomotion : MonoBehaviour
{
    PlayerManager playerManager;
    AnimatorManager animatorManager;
    InputManager inputManager;
    Vector3 moveDirection;

    public float gravityIntensity = -40;
    public float jumpHeight = 50;

    public bool isJumping;

    [Header("Falling")]
    public float inAirTimer;
    public float leapingVelocity;
    public float fallingVelocity;
    public LayerMask groundLayer;
    public float rayCastHeightOffset = 0.5f;

    [Header("Movement Flags")]
    public bool isSprinting;
    public bool isGrounded;

    Transform cameraObject;
    Rigidbody playerRigidbody;
    public float movementSpeed = 7;
    public float rotationSpeed = 15;
    
    private void Awake()
    {
        animatorManager = GetComponent<AnimatorManager>();
        playerManager = GetComponent<PlayerManager>();
        inputManager = GetComponent<InputManager>();
        playerRigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        cameraObject = Camera.main.transform;
    }

    private void HandleMovement()
    {
        // Calculate the movement direction separately for horizontal and vertical inputs.
        Vector3 moveDirection = cameraObject.forward * inputManager.verticalInput;
        moveDirection += cameraObject.right * inputManager.horizontalInput;

        // Ensure that the movement direction is normalized to move at a consistent speed.
        if (moveDirection.magnitude > 1f)
        {
            moveDirection.Normalize();
        }

        // Zero out the y-component to prevent tilting or flying.
        moveDirection.y = 0;

        // Apply the movement speed to the normalized direction vector.
        Vector3 movementVelocity = moveDirection * movementSpeed;

        // Set the velocity to the rigidbody for movement.
        playerRigidbody.velocity = movementVelocity;
    }


    private void HandleRotation()
    {
        if (isJumping)
        {
            return;
        }
        Vector3 inputDirection = cameraObject.forward * inputManager.verticalInput + cameraObject.right * inputManager.horizontalInput;
        inputDirection.Normalize();
        inputDirection.y = 0;

        if (inputDirection != Vector3.zero)
        {
            Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(inputDirection);
            Quaternion playerRotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, targetRotation, rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

            transform.rotation = playerRotation;
        }
    }

    public void HandleAllMovement()
    {
        HandleFallingAndLanding();
        if (playerManager.isInteracting)
        {
            return;
        }
        HandleMovement();
        HandleRotation();
    }

    private void HandleFallingAndLanding()
    {
        RaycastHit hit;
        Vector3 rayCastOrigin = transform.position;
        rayCastOrigin.y = rayCastOrigin.y + rayCastHeightOffset;
        if (!isGrounded && !isJumping)
        {
            if (!playerManager.isInteracting)
            {
                animatorManager.PlayTargetAnimation("Falling", true);
            }

            inAirTimer += Time.deltaTime;
            playerRigidbody.AddForce(transform.forward * leapingVelocity);
            playerRigidbody.AddForce(fallingVelocity * inAirTimer * -Vector3.up);
        }

        if (Physics.SphereCast(rayCastOrigin, 0.2f, -Vector3.up, out hit, groundLayer))
        {
            if(!isGrounded && !playerManager.isInteracting)
            {
                animatorManager.PlayTargetAnimation("LandSoft", true);
            }

            inAirTimer = 0;
            isGrounded = true;
        }
        else
        {
            isGrounded = false;
        }
    }

    public void HandleJumping()
    {
        if (isGrounded)
        {
            animatorManager.animator.SetBool("isJumping", true);
            animatorManager.PlayTargetAnimation("Jump", false);

            float jumpingVelocity = Mathf.Sqrt(-2 * gravityIntensity * jumpHeight);
            Vector3 playerVelocity = moveDirection;
            playerVelocity.y = jumpingVelocity;
            playerRigidbody.velocity = playerVelocity;
        }
    }
}
```

My Camera Code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CameraManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    InputManager inputManager;
    public Transform targetTransform;
    private Vector3 cameraFollowVelocity = Vector3.zero;
    public float cameraFollowSpeed = 0.2f;
    public float cameraLookSpeed = 2;
    public float cameraPivotSpeed = 2;
    public float desiredHeight = 1.0f;
    public Transform cameraPivot;


    private void Awake()
    {
        inputManager = FindObjectOfType<InputManager>();
        targetTransform = FindObjectOfType<PlayerManager>().transform;
    }
    private void Update()
    {
        FollowTarget();
        RotateCamera();
    }

    public void FollowTarget()
    {
        Vector3 targetPosition = Vector3.SmoothDamp(transform.position, targetTransform.position, ref cameraFollowVelocity, cameraFollowSpeed);
        transform.position = targetPosition;
    }

    public void RotateCamera()
    {
        Vector3 lookAtDirection = targetTransform.position - cameraPivot.position;
        lookAtDirection.y = 0;

        if (lookAtDirection != Vector3.zero)
        {
            // Calculate the target rotation to look at the player
            Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(lookAtDirection);

            // Smoothly rotate the camera pivot towards the target rotation
            cameraPivot.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(cameraPivot.rotation, targetRotation, cameraLookSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
}
```

What can I do to improve my camera rotation?

Comment: A bit confused about the description ... is it only the camera rotation making it look weird or is your player actually moving in circles? From your play movement code I would not obviously spot why it moves in circles ... maybe some visuals would help to understand the issue better